# Count the length of JSON array and access the json element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I access Json sessionInfo and lenght of json array.Here is my JSON array:

```
  {
"data": [
    {
        "sessionInfo": {
            "sessionUserId": 1,
            "startTime": "1418106218946",
            "endTime": "1418106218946"
        },
        "observations": [
            {
                "obLocation": "location1",
                "obHcwType": "hcwtype1",
                "obMoment": "moment1",
                "obItem": "item1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sessionInfo": {
            "sessionUserId": 2,
            "startTime": "1418106218946",
            "endTime": "1418106218946"
        },
        "observations": [
            {
                "obLocation": "location2",
                "obHcwType": "hcwtype2",
                "obMoment": "moment2",
                "obItem": "item2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

and I'm receiving JSON like this:

```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

And my count function is

```
       echo count($arr['data']);
```

But I'm getting output 1, it should come 2 as this array has two element. I also checked on Json editor, where JSON format is correct.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem as you've illustrated it. I would make sure that the contents of $json are as you expect.

Comment: Can you provide us with the output of print_r($arr)?

Comment: Thanks @twh I'm getting 1.  But here is two element inside the json array.

Comment: I already gave the output of the print_r($arr). Please check it out.

Comment: From the comment below I presume the JSon string is what you get when you print_r($arr)? in that case your json_decode function is not working right. Or did you post the output of print_r($arr) somewhere where I am just too blind to find it? json_decode needs PHP 5.2 do you have that installed on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a different url/file? I coppied your code exact and it works 100%.

Make sure the `php://input` is correct. Try store the JSON in an external file and try link to that file.

**EDIT**

try this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('something.json');
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr['data']); $i++) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

[image: code]

[image: result]

There you can see the exact code, and output. As you can see, the same JSON is being output, and then the count under it.

If you're still not getting it right, then you're using a different JSON source, or you have something overriding the variables in PHP

Comment: Thanks @VaMoose as you said Its also working fine but problem is that I want count of array element but getting only 1.

Comment: No, I'm still getting 1. Actually this json is coming from post method from another file. @VaMoose

Comment: @RaghavSingh Then you're using different JSON, not the one you posted. The above code works with the JSON you provided.

Comment: Through print_ r function I'm getting same Json in my output.

Comment: Actually problem was that I was already using json decode array. Now I got your point Thanks a lot @VaMoose.